# Div above div positioning using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this code that I don't really understand why it works:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">    
             #divWraper
             {                              
                position: relative;
             }                          
             #divBig
             {      
                width: 500px;
                height: 300px;              
                background: Green;
                border: 1px dashed yellow;              
            }

            #divSmall
            {
            position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0px;
                width: 500px;
                height: 100px;
                background: Red;                              
                z-index: 200;         
                opacity: 0.5;
                filter: alpha(opacity = 50);                    
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body> 
      <div id="divWraper">       
        <div id="divBig"></div>    
        <div id="divSmall"></div>       
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How does, this style makes the layout "work" (if I omit it, it brakes the layout):

```
#divWraper
{                              
     position: relative;
}
```

I thought this is just for positioning the outer div , but it also effects the children...

Please provide a clear explanation :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `position:absolute` on an element, the top, left, right and bottom properties are based on the nearest positioned parent element, or to document body if there are none.

Take the following example:

```
<div id="parent" style="position:relative">
  <div>blah</div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div style="position:absolute">Here is some more content<div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `absolute` positioned div here will be positioned relative to the div with the `parent` id, because that is the nearest positioned element.  If I add `style="position:relative"` to the `id="wrapper"` div, it will be positioned relative to that div instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a css trick. It goes like this:

**If you set the parent div position to relative and the child divs position to absolute then child divs will remain inside the parent div even though their position is absolute.**

See: [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) for more explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the child divs to base their positioning relative to the parent div, the parent div must have positioning set to something other than static (which it is by default).  Making the parent `relative` makes all children who are not `fixed` position themselves relative to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

`absolute positioned` element are relative to the next **positioned** parent element. If none of the parent elements are positioned than relative to the `body tag`, so if you take out the `position: relative`, the `div.small` is positioned relative to the body with bottom: 0

Answer (score 0):

You can position two or more elements above one another using this technique:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <element>
       <element>
       <element>
    </tr>
</table>
```

"element"s here are positioned in vertical order

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).